# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scrapping cricket test match details i have tested the results now i want to save it inside the file. while saving the html in file I am getting `str object cannot be interedpreted as an integer`

this is my code

```
for i in range(0, 2000):
    url = 'http://search.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/match/search.html?search=test;all=1;page=%s' %i
    html = requests.get(url)

    print ('Checking page %s of 2000' %(i+1))

    soupy = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    time.sleep(1)
    for new_host in soupy.findAll('a', {'class' : 'srchPlyrNmTxt'}):
        try:
            new_host = new_host['href']
        except:
            continue
        odiurl = BASE_URL + new_host
        new_host = odiurl
        print(new_host)
        html = requests.get(new_host).text
        with open('espncricinfo-fc/{0!s}'.format(str.split(new_host, "/")[4]), "wb") as f:
                f.write(html)
```

**I am getting this error `str object cannot be interedpreted as an integer`**

I am getting error in this line

**with open('espncricinfo-fc/{0!s}'.format(str.split(new_host, "/")[4]), "wb") as f:**

Comment: Where are you getting the error? (which line?)

Comment: last two lines i am getting error

Comment: What is BASE_URL?

Comment: You're writing in byte mode (`"wb"`), but I'm guessing you're trying to write `str` data rather than `bytes`. What happens if you change `requests.get(new_host).text` to `requests.get(new_host).text.encode()`?

Comment: @ShivamSingh BASE_URL = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com'

Comment: @JaminSore can you pelase make an answer so that i can try..

Comment: @ShivamSingh's answer would have the same effect ... looks like it's something else.

Comment: the error is in the with open line

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. I cannot reproduce it though.

Comment: @ShivamSingh i have mentioned the line where i am getting the error . just edit the question

Comment: When you do `except:` `continue` do you mean to continue the loop `for new_host in ...` or do you want to continue the loop `for i in range`

Comment: Why not new_host.split(“/”)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.x, try changing the last line to

```
f.write(bytes(html, 'UTF-8'))
```

Also try this,

```
new_host = str(new_host['href'])
```

Comment: I am getting the same error as before 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: You need to fix the split function, It should be `str.split(new_host, "/")[6]` and `BASE_URL = "http://espncricinfo.com"`

Comment: Shivam done both of these above edit but still it is not saving in the file.

Comment: What are you getting exactly? Does 'espncricinfo-fc' folder exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184446/discussion-between-tayyab-gulsher-vohra-and-shivam-singh).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `print` statement.
It should read

`print('checking %d etc.' % (i + 1))`

Comment: its working i have checked i have also removed this line but the error remains same..

Comment: What line number, does `new_host` as a class have a `__str__` method. You `print` it and use `str.split` in the final line

Comment: What does `soupy.findall('a', { ... })` return. A range or a list of strings. You set `new_host` to `BASE_URL + new_host`. After setting it to a dictionary lookup `new_host['href']`